# Creating An Oval Shaped Progress Bar in Swift

Tags: swift3, progress-bar

I am trying to create a progress bar like this in this exact shape:

[image]

I have tried many different things, but nothing has worked

Answer (score -1):

you can use video of this progress bar loading using MediaPlayer library in swift and i sure it will work :)